# How to read the VersionInfoVersion of my setup to compare with the existing version

Tags: inno-setup

In my installer, I have to check if the version being installed is lower than that of the application that is already installed on the computer.

If so, I have to close the installer without allowing the installation.

So, I have this code bellow:

```
if GetVersionNumbersString(ExpandConstant('{app}\bin\application.exe'), Version) then
begin
...
end;
```

This returns to me, the version number of application on computer.
My question is:

How do I read the info in `VersionInfoVersion` of mySetup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To correctly compare version numbers, you will need to do a numeric compare of each component of the version number.

You can use ISPP's [`GetFileVersion()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_getfileversion.htm) to get the textual version number that you're installing at compile time and `{#emit...}` it into a PascalScript string variable, or use PascalScript's [`GetVersionNumbersString()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getversionnumbersstring.htm) at runtime and pass `ExpandConstants('{srcexe}')`. You can then use PascalScript's `GetVersionNumbersString()` function again to get the textual version of the application to be replaced.

When you have both of these in PascalScript string variables, you can use the [`CompareVersion()`](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=DirectX_-_How_to_detect_DirectX_version) function to do the actual comparison.

Comment: Note that it is legal for the textual version to include non-numeric tokens (eg. codenames).  If you have elected to do this with your application and/or setup then you will have to directly compare the binary versions instead of trying to parse the text version.  (Generally, I believe that comparing the binary versions is better anyway.)  You can get the binary version via `GetVersionNumbers()`.

Comment: @Miral `GetVersionNumbersString()` gets the numerical version as a dotted string doesn't it?

Comment: I am not certain, but I do not believe so.

Comment: @Miral I've just tested and it gets the binary/numerical file version and formats it as a dotted quad string. [(example)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2931731/GetVersionNumbersString.PNG)